# Why is $ab(a+b)+cd(c+d)= (cd-ab)(c+d)?$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I got stuck on a polynomial problem, and decided to search up the solution. I found someone else here who asked it a while ago, but I can't understand their answer.(link: [Find all integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a+b+c+d=0$ and $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 =24$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499544/find-all-integers-a-b-c-d-such-that-abcd-0-and-a3-b3-c3-d3-24))

This part specifically:

[image]

In my attempt, I managed to arrive at the same conclusion that $ab(a+b)+cd(c+d)=-8$, but was not able to continue further. This factorization doesn't even seem to make sense. Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: $a+b+c+d=0$. Then? $a+b=-(c+d)$

Comment: Actually extremely simple, feel dumb now